# Lists in Python: Sum of Words with Specific Length

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax or logic here as this seems fairly straightforward. Do I need to split the words into chars?

> Count how many words in a list have length 5.

This is what I have so far:

```
def countWords(lst):
    total=0
    for word in lst:
        if len(word)==5:
            total+=1
    return total
```

Update: There are great answers and explanations here, thank you! Unfortunately, I think the activecode is just not working on this site: https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/Lists/Exercises.html: Question 10.

Comment: Fix your indentation first.

Comment: and don't use `sum` for object names as it is used for built-in method `sum()`

Comment: return should be intended inside

Comment: that should  work now

Comment: also, please don't update the code in question as it makes the answers meaningless

Comment: `return len([x for x in lst if len(x)==5])`

Comment: `return sum(len(word)==5 for word in lst)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to fix your indentation, and then you probably want to use another name for your `sum` variable. I've changed it to `found` below for you.

```
def countWords(lst):
   found = 0
   for word in lst:
      if len(word) == 5:
         found += 1
   return found
```

Then you'll have to call the function, so

`countWords(lst)`

where lst is the list of words.

Answer (score 2):

the code correct and will provide you, total no of words having a length of 5.

you don't need to count the individual character of a word as `len(str)` provide the total no of characters inside the word.

to make this solution more scalable and testable for different length words, you can provide length as an option in the functional argument. setting default word length equals to 5 default and check it inside the function. Adding code for it

```
def countWords(lst,word_length=5):
    total=0
    for word in lst:
        if len(word)==word_length:
            total+=1
    return total
```

if you want solution in single line

```
def countWords(lst, word_length=5):
    return sum(1 for word in lst if len(word)==word_length)
```

Comment: This single line solution was my favourite of all the solutions listed, mine included. I find it very easy to read and follow

Answer (score 2):

First, indentation is very important in Python, also avoid using built-in names like sum, len etc. Also, function name should be in lower case, with words separated by an underscore. here is the multiline solution

```
def count_words(lst):
    word_count = 0
    for word in lst:
        if len(word) == 5:
            word_count += 1
    return word_count
```

and here is the one-liner solution

```
def count_words(lst):
    return len([word for word in lst if len(word) == 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this more directly, by using a **list comprehension** to find all of the words, and counting from there.

```
def countWords(lst):
    return sum([int(len(word) == 5) for word in lst])
```

This iterates through all of the words, checking the length, and adding up the resulting Booleans: `True` is `,` False`is 0, by definition.  Actually, you don't *need* the`int` conversion, but some people prefer it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You must remember that in Python, the indentation is important. In your case, since `return sum` is not indented, it is considered outside of your countWords() function.

The valid code is:

```py
def countWords(lst):
    count=0
    for word in lst:
        if len(word)==5:
            count+=1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an indentation problem, check your indentation in the Idle (it makes it more obvious).

Since you are new to python, I will show you some cool ways to do this in python style.

```
return (len([word for word in lst if len(word) == 5]))
```

```
# using the filter function 
def isWord(word):
    return len(word) == 3

#an_iterator = filter(isWord, lst)
return len(list (filter(isWord, lst)))
```

```
# using lambda
#an_iterator = filter(lambda word: len(word), lst)
return len(list (filter(lambda word: len(word), lst)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve the same using a map + lambda to single out the words in the list of length 5.

```py
lst = ["12345", "123", "1234", "abcde", "123", "1234", "abcde"]


def countWords(lst):
    return sum(map(lambda word: len(word) == 5, lst))


print(countWords(lst))
```

outputs:

```
3
```